# pass generated parameter to lock label in JEnkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm unable to pass script generated parameter to jenkins lock label, I'm generating this value based on branch and hence the need to pass custom label to lock.
If the same parameter is defined as build params it's accepting.

generated parameter through script and tried passing, it's not accepting.

e.g.

```
  stage('determine testbed') {
    steps {
      script {
        env.DUT_LABEL_TEST = 'SRTD3Composability'
      }
    }
}
...
...
stage('TD3 Sanity') {
options {
  lock(label: "${env.DUT_LABEL_TEST"}, quantity: 1, \
  variable: 'TD3_SWITCH', resource: null)
}
}
```

error -
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The resource label does not exist: env.DUT_LABEL_TEST.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a problem with the syntax and access to this variable: `DUT_LABEL_TEST`

Try doing it like this:

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
            stage('determine testbed') {
                 steps {
                     script {
                         DUT_LABEL_TEST = 'SRTD3Composability'
                     }
                 }
             }
             stage('TD3 Sanity') {
                 options {
                     lock(label: DUT_LABEL_TEST, quantity: 1, \
                     variable: 'TD3_SWITCH', resource: null)
             }
         }
     }
}
```

or try using an environment block

```
pipeline {
        agent any
        environment {
          DUT_LABEL_TEST = 'SRTD3Composability'
        }

        stages {
          stage('TD3 Sanity') {
             options {
               lock(label: "${env.DUT_LABEL_TES}", quantity: 1, \
               variable: 'TD3_SWITCH', resource: null)
                 }
             }
         }
    }
```